# How does xmpp s2s work?

Tags: node.js, xmpp, ejabberd, xmppframework, node-xmpp

I have had hard time understanding the complete information flow in s2s interaction. There aren't many documents available on internet.

I am using nodejs based xmpp-server to set up a xmpp server which is built on top of node-xmpp. This is working perfectly for a single server system but development hasn't been done in "xmpp-server" module for s2s support. Packages like ejabberd do support s2s but there isn't much documentation available on to how this whole thing works.

Another thing to note is that I don't want multiple host names. All I want is another instance of the xmpp server that I am already running on one machine. Both can use the same database.

Comment: I doubt that "There aren't many documents available..." on XMPP. It's an open protocol, everything describing it is freely available. And please don't ask multiple questions in the same post.

Answer (score 3):

http://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc6120.html#examples-s2s   Complete example using tls and certificates.  The document specify the core XMPP protocol so you should found answers to most of your questions there.

http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0220.html   DNS Dialback protocol, if s2s authentication isn't performed using certificates you will need this.